# How can I install AVG Anti Virus on a computer without internet connection?

Tags: installation, proxy, avg-antivirus

I downloaded AVG Anti Virus on one computer and tried to copy it to a stand alone computer but it says that I need to connect to the internet.

Is there a way to bypass the proxy and the need of internet connection?

Comment: Though if the computer is stand-alone do you really need anti virus software? You can check any exe you might want to install on another machine and your main vector, the internet, isn't available.

Comment: @ Brendan, You might explain why you need to do it this way, maybe there is a better answer to your real problem.

Comment: After some searching I found the 2016 full installer: http://www.avg.com/ww-en/download.prd-afh-free

Answer (score 1):

Is the installer you are using the offline installer or the online one? The offline one should be around ~`170-190 MB` depending upon your OS (32 vs 64 bit), whereas the online one is ~`5.1 MB`. You can find the offline installer [here](http://www.mytechguide.org/8566/avg-antivirus-2011-free/) (updated Aug 10, 2011).

Do note that to update your virus definitions at a later date, you would need to download the update definitions as mentioned by `music2myear:`

> After you've installed AVG using the offline installer Jay linked to,
>   once a week or so, [download definition update files](http://free.avg.com/us-en/download-update) to keep the
>   antivirus software up to date and scanning for the most recent
>   viruses.

Answer (score 1):

Despite what Jay says, you do not need to download and reinstall a fresh version of the AVG app to keep it updated.

After you've installed AVG using the offline installer Jay linked to, once a week or so, [download definition update files](http://free.avg.com/us-en/download-update) to keep the antivirus software up to date and scanning for the most recent viruses.

Comment: +1, I did not know that separate definition update files were available. Er, it seems that I have used all my votes for today, but I shall def. upvote you once I can.

Answer (score 0):

Use this link to download the full version installer. Don't forget to download update files too,

http://free.avg.com/us-en/download-free-all-product